# Type mismatch when getting the variable value from Repository in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm using the LiveData and ViewModel from architecture components on Android.

This is my repository class -

```
class DataRepository {

    var imagePath : String = ""
}
```

This is my ViewModel where I want to get the value of **imagePath** from the repository after the value in the Repository has been updated -

```
class DataViewModel : ViewModel() {

    internal lateinit var imagePath : MutableLiveData<String>
    imagePath.value = DataRepository().imagePath

}
```

The problem is that **imagePath** in the DataRepository is of type **String** and the imagePath in the DataViewModel is of type **MutableLiveData**.

How would I assign the imagePath value from repository to the one in ViewModel ? Do I need to do any type casting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method: setValue in MutableLiveData class. Hence, you can try this:

```
internal lateinit var imagePath : MutableLiveData<String>
imagePath.setValue(DataRepository().imagePath)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I always need to use Room when using LiveData and ViewModel ? Because I haven't see a tutorial for LiveData and ViewModel without Room

Comment: If you do not store your data to database (sqlite), you do not need to use Room